# Why are these two groups not isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers

I am trying to understand a proof (from the German book "Einführung in die Kryptografie" by Johannes Buchmann) that there are at most $(n-1)/4$ non-witnesses against the primality of $n$ in the Miller-Rabin algorithm that are coprime to $n$.

The Miller-Rabin test is stated in the following way:

Let $s = \max\{r \in \mathbb{N}: 2^r \text{ divides } n-1\}$ and $d = (n-1)/2^s$.
If $n$ is a prime number and if $a$ is a number coprime to $n$ then

$$ a^d \equiv 1 \pmod{n} \tag{A} $$

or there is a $r$ in the set $\{0,1,\ldots,s-1\}$ such that

$$a^{2^rd} \equiv -1 \pmod{n} \tag{B} $$

I have a problem with the following proof:

Let $n \ge 3$ be an odd composite number. We want to estimate how many numbers $a \in \{0,1,\ldots,s-1\}$ exist for which $\gcd(a,n-1) = 1$ and both  $(A)$ and $(B)$ hold. If there is no such $a$ we are fi

We set the prime factorisation of $n$ to $n = \prod_{p\mid n} p^{e(p)}$.

The author considers the following two subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\times}$
$$\begin{align*}
K &= \{ a + n\mathbb{Z} : \gcd(a,n) = 1 \text{ and } a^{n-1} \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{p^{e(p)}} \text{ for all primes $p$ such that } p|n\}\\
L &= \{ a + n\mathbb{Z} : \gcd(a,n) = 1 \text{ and } a^{m} \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{n}\}
\end{align*}$$

In the coure of the proof the author considers the groups $L$ and $K$ and distinguishes between them. I do not understand  why these two groups are not just the same by the Chinese remainder theorem, as all $p^{e(p)}$ are pairwise coprime and $n$ is by definition the product of these $p^{e(p)}$. Could you tell me what I am getting wrong?

Comment: The set $K$ includes cosets of $a$ such that $a^{n-1}\equiv-1$ modulo some prime powers and $\equiv+1$ modulo some other prime powers. In the set $L$ the same sign must occur for all prime powers dividing $n$ (as per the Chinese Remainder Theorem).

Comment: This question has large overlap with [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012774/questions-about-a-proof-of-the-error-bound-of-the-miller-rabin-test): answerers and readers would do well to read both.